# Facebook Graph API v2.9 comment plugin count without access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

## TLDR;

I want to be able to use the Javascript SDK to get the comment plugin count for a webpage. In the Graph API versions before 2.9 I could access this with the `share` endpoint without an access token, but since version 2.9 `share` is deprecated and replaced with `engagement`, which now requires an access token. I am aware that I shouldn't expose the app token to the client, so does anyone know how this can be achieved client-side using the Javascript SDK? The versions of the Graph API before 2.9 allowed me to do this using the `share` field, but this change will cause me to significantly change my code as it requires me to move my code from the client-side to the server-side. If possible I'd like to not have to do this. Does this change also not render the Javsacript SDK a little redundant, as all requests require an access token that shouldn't be accessible to the client?

## Long version

For the Facebook Graph API v2.8 and lower I could get the count of the number of comments posted on a webpage that has implemented the Facebook comment plugin using the `share` field like this:

```
FB.api(
    "/",
    {
        fields: "share{comment_count}",
        id: url
    },
    function (response) {
        if (!!response.error) return;

        var commentCount = Number(response.share.comment_count);
    }
);
```

The same thing is accessible by making this HTTP GET Request:
[https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/?id=URL_HERE&fields=share{comment_count}](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/?id=URL_HERE&fields=share%7Bcomment_count%7D)

Notice also, *it doesn't require an access token* which makes sense as this is publicly available info so no authorisation is necessary. This makes it simple to get the comment count using JavaScript on the client's browser using the Javascript SDK.

According to the change log from [Graph API version 2.9](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.9#gapi-changes-general) onwards:

> - `GET /{url}/share` - The `share` endpoint has been removed and replaced
>     with:
>
>   - `engagement` field with subfields:
>
>     - comment_count
>     - comment_plugin_count
>     - reaction_count
>     - share_count

As a side note, if I look at the [documentation for the `engagement` endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/engagement), it doesn't mention the subfields mentioned in the change log.

But my problem is that calling this HTTP GET request: [https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/?id=URL_HERE&fields=engagement{comment_plugin_count}](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/?id=URL_HERE&fields=engagement%7Bcomment_plugin_count%7D) requires me to have an `access_token`. If I use my app token it works. How can this be called on the client-side without exposing the app token? This was a simple task before using the `share` endpoint, but it seems unnecessarily difficult using the `engagement` endpoint considering the comment plugin count should always be publicly accessible without any authorisation.

Comment: The only safe client-side implementation would be to ask the website visitors to login to your Facebook app first, so that you can then use their user access token to make the request. Other than that, it’s server-side only.

Comment: Isn't this a step backwards? Why would the Graph API require me to authenticate a request that doesn't need any specific permission to access the data it's request? The comment plugin count value should be accessible publicly without needing any authentication, which is/was true of the `share` endpoint. Is there any other way I could receive the comment count without an access token?

Comment: I am surprised this was even possible until now, because with the introduction of API v2.0 access tokens became mandatory to use with all calls, with the documented exception of the profile picture endpoints. Looks like they had implemented an exception for the share count as well - https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/?id=http://example.com/&fields=share%7Bcomment_count%7D works, https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/?id=http://example.com/ only gives an error

Comment: Guess you can file a bug report and ask if they plan to enable this again for engagements; but I rather doubt you’d have any luck with that.